# Error undefined is not an object(evaluating 'source.sourceLinks.push') D3.JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

After making my Sankey Diagram work I wanted to change some stuff in the JSON input file,
I added two more values to have them displayed when I over a nodes but I run into an issue which leads me here.
So, After adding these two values my diagram simply won't work again, first with the two values added it's output the same error in the title here's the code for both

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "node": 0,
      "name": "Success"
    },
    {
      "node": 1,
      "name": "Failed"
    },
    {
      "node": 2,
      "name": "Cantwell"
    },
    {
      "node": 3,
      "name": "Denmark"
    },
    {
      "node": 4,
      "name": "Eastville"
    },
    {
      "node": 5,
      "name": "Edgemere"
    },
    {
      "node": 6,
      "name": "Elmira"
    },
    {
      "node": 7,
      "name": "Eudora"
    },
    {
      "node": 8,
      "name": "Greigsville"
    },
    {
      "node": 9,
      "name": "Mosquito"
    },
    {
      "node": 10,
      "name": "Pablo"
    },
    {
      "node": 11,
      "name": "Ribera"
    },
    {
      "node": 12,
      "name": "Sands"
    },
    {
      "node": 13,
      "name": "Scioto"
    },
    {
      "node": 14,
      "name": "Sisters"
    },
    {
      "node": 15,
      "name": "Swormville"
    }
  ],
    "links": [
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 47,
        "SPL": 0.6619718309859155,
        "Success_Rate": 0.6619718309859155
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 24,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 3,
        "value": 60,
        "SPL": 0.4225352112676056,
        "Success_Rate": 0.4225352112676056
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 3,
        "value": 11,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 4,
        "value": 56,
        "SPL": 0.2622788010111954,
        "Success_Rate": 0.26291079812206575
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 4,
        "value": 15,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 5,
        "value": 65,
        "SPL": 0.22839118041582832,
        "Success_Rate": 0.22887323943661972
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 5,
        "value": 6,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 6,
        "value": 62,
        "SPL": 0.17405036278275715,
        "Success_Rate": 0.17464788732394365
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 6,
        "value": 9,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 7,
        "value": 64,
        "SPL": 0.14989297213677982,
        "Success_Rate": 0.15023474178403756
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 7,
        "value": 7,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 8,
        "value": 53,
        "SPL": 0.10663983903420524,
        "Success_Rate": 0.10663983903420524
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 8,
        "value": 18,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 9,
        "value": 45,
        "SPL": 0.07922535211267606,
        "Success_Rate": 0.07922535211267606
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 9,
        "value": 26,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 10,
        "value": 38,
        "SPL": 0.0594679186228482,
        "Success_Rate": 0.0594679186228482
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 10,
        "value": 33,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 11,
        "value": 60,
        "SPL": 0.08438456827924068,
        "Success_Rate": 0.08450704225352113
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 11,
        "value": 11,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 12,
        "value": 56,
        "SPL": 0.07170294494238155,
        "Success_Rate": 0.07170294494238157
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 12,
        "value": 15,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 13,
        "value": 35,
        "SPL": 0.04107981220657277,
        "Success_Rate": 0.04107981220657277
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 13,
        "value": 0,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 14,
        "value": 64,
        "SPL": 63.89878163333731,
        "Success_Rate": 0.06933911159263272
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 14,
        "value": 43,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      },
      {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 15,
        "value": 62,
        "SPL": 0.061367069486404836,
        "Success_Rate": 0.06143001007049345
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 15,
        "value": 9,
        "SPL": 0,
        "Success_Rate": 0
      }
    ]
  }
```

And the code to run the graph

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg1 = d3.select("#sceneLevel")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Color scale used
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

// Set the sankey diagram properties
var sankey = d3.sankey()
.nodeWidth(36)
.nodePadding(5)
.size([width, height]);

// load the data
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/augustin-laurent/Visualization_Tool/master/data.json", function(error, graph) {

// Constructs a new Sankey generator with the default settings.
sankey
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .layout(1);

// add in the links
var link = svg1.append("g")
.selectAll(".link")
.data(graph.links)
.enter()
.append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", sankey.link() )
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
  .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; })
  

// add in the nodes
var node = svg1.append("g")
.selectAll(".node")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
  .call(d3.drag()
    .subject(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("start", function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
    .on("drag", dragmove));

// add the rectangles for the nodes
node
.append("rect")
  .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
  .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
// Add hover text
.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name + "\n" + "SPL is " + d.SPL + "And Success_rate is" + d.Success_rate; });

// add in the title for the nodes
node
  .append("text")
    .attr("x", -6)
    
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("transform", null)
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .filter(function(d) { return d.x < width / 2; })
    .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
    .attr("text-anchor", "start");

// the function for moving the nodes
function dragmove(d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("transform",
          "translate("
            + d.x + ","
            + (d.y = Math.max(
                0, Math.min(height - d.dy, d3.event.y))
              ) + ")");
  sankey.relayout();
  link.attr("d", sankey.link() );
}
});
```

And here is the HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load the sankey.js function -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery@master/LIB/sankey.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<section class="container">
<div id="sceneLevel"></div>
<ul id="episodeMenu">

</ul>
<div id="episodeLevel"></div>
</section>
<!-- Add style to links or they won't appear properly-->
<style>
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: .2;
}
.link:hover {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}
.background path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.foreground path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}

.brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .3;
  stroke: #fff;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
  cursor: move;
}
</style>

<script src="sankey.js"></script>
<script src="parralelCoordinate.js"></script>
```

So I try to revert it to the previous state, and the error changed to undefined is not an object(evaluating 'graph.links'), with this, the error came from my JS file.
SoI tried to tweak for two days and still haven't figure out what is wrong with my code
I will appreciate the help, and will I'm here I would like to make an interaction when I click on the links between the nodes if you have a hint I would gladly appreciate the help.

Comment: Is your JSON sample the one before or after the change?

Comment: No it's the new one the one used before is the same except the field SPL and Success_rate where not here, that's why I tried to revert it because I thought that it's only limited to one value

Comment: I don't see those attributes are somehow used in your code... Are you sure it will work if you remove them from your data?

Comment: How yeah true I forgot to make the line 65 back to when I don't try to tweak the code the original was : .text(function(d) { return d.name + "\n" + "SPL is " + d.SPL + "And Success_rate is" + d.Success_rate; }); but this don't change anything and even if I removed It I got an error while it was working a like 2 days ago

Comment: Did you try envelope parts of your code with `try/catch` to locate the line that produces the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was simply a ; missing here `.sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; })` but the value still being undefined cause it doesn't read it from the JSON file